# Closed formula for a certain infinite series

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, real-analysis, analytic-number-theory

I came across this problem while doing some simplifications.

So, I like to ask

> **QUESTION.** Is there a closed formula for the evaluation of this series?
> $$\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{a}b\right)}{a^2b^2}$$
> where the sum runs over all pairs of positive integers that are relatively prime.

Comment: An infinitite sum is an incorrect math term, the sum of a series is a correct one.

Comment: Math experiment done with Mathematica `Sum[Piecewise[{{Cos[a/b]/a^2/b^2, GCD[a, b] == 1}, {0, True}}], {a, 1,
    230}, {b, 1, 230}] // N` results in `0.999507`. The summation up to $300$ produces $1.00087$.

Comment: @user64494 why? "infinite sum" is a correct math term, and refers to the sum of a family of numbers, which is the present case. "Sum of a series" is a correct term, yet not applicable here, since the OP's one is not a series.

Comment: @PietroMajer: An infinite sum cannot be calculated. The question under consideration is about a double series which absolutely converges.

Comment: @user64494 : As Pietro Majer said, "infinite sum" is a correct term, and $\sum_{x\in X}f(x)$ can be defined for any (say) real-valued function $f$ on any set $X$. One of a number of mutually equivalent ways to do that is as follows: $\sum_{x\in X}f(x):=\int_X f\,d\nu$, where $\nu$ is the counting measure on (the $\sigma$-algebra of all subsets of) $X$, if the integral exists.

Comment: @T. Amdeberhan  never follow suggestions from anonymous  sources  :)

Comment: This question on MathStackExchange asked a similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452028/evaluate-sum-limits-m-n-in-d-m-n-frac1n2-m2-where-gcdm-n-1?noredirect=1 The method of solution given there in the accepted answer can be easily applied to the OPs case, similar approach using Mobius transformation.

Comment: @user64494 On the other hand, I think we all agree that an "infinitite sum" is an incorrect math term :-)

Comment: @PietroMajer Read my comment (and user64494's original) carefully -- I did not write "infinite sum"! :-)

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda ops… I’m a very incorrect reader! :)

Comment: @PietroMajer and Iosif Pinelis: I concur with you.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Apply Möbius summation, the formula for $\sum_{n>=1}\cos(2\pi n x)/n^2$ to obtain:

$$11/4-45\zeta(3)/\pi^3=1.00543...\;$$

Comment: GH from MO has given much detail in the answer below. Let me just expand on what Henri Cohen referred to as Möbius summation: $\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{\cos(a/b)}{a^2b^2}=\sum_{m,n}\sum_{d\vert(m,n)}\frac{\mu(d)}{m^2n^2}=\sum_k\frac{\mu(k)}{k^4}\sum_{x,y}\frac1{x^2y^2}=\frac1{\zeta(4)}\sum_{x,y}\frac1{x^2y^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for a cute answer, Henri Cohen.

Answer (score 46):

Let me add the details for Henri Cohen's nice answer, without claiming any originality. We have
$$\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{m}n\right)}{m^2n^2}=\zeta(4)\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{a}b\right)}{a^2b^2}.$$
On the other hand, by the identity (cf. Ron Gordon's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552640/series-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cosnxn2))
$$\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\cos(mx)}{m^2}=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{\pi x}{2}+\zeta(2),\qquad 0\leq x\leq 2\pi,$$
we also have
$$\sum_{m,n\geq 1}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{m}n\right)}{m^2n^2}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}\left(\frac{n^{-2}}{4}-\frac{\pi n^{-1}}{2}+\zeta(2)\right)=\frac{\zeta(4)}{4}-\frac{\pi\zeta(3)}{2}+\zeta(2)^2.$$
Comparing the right hand sides of the first and third equation, we conclude that
$$\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{a}b\right)}{a^2b^2}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\pi\zeta(3)}{2\zeta(4)}+\frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)}.$$
Here we have $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ and $\zeta(4)=\pi^4/90$, therefore
$$\sum_{(a,b)=1}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{a}b\right)}{a^2b^2}=\frac{11}{4}-\frac{45\zeta(3)}{\pi^3}.$$

Comment: Could you give a reference (or derivation) for the identity in the second display?

Comment: And a reference for the first identity, please.

Comment: @JoshuaStucky: Reference added.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: The first identity follows readily by grouping the pairs $(m,n)$ according to their greatest common divisor. That is, we write $m=ad$, $n=bd$ with $d=\gcd(m,n)$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: @GHfromMO: thank you for furnishing the details.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: You are welcome!